# If strings are immutable, does that mean a value reassignment creates a new string object with the same name?

Tags: c#, string, object, immutability

Eg:

```
string test = "abcde"; // "abcde"
test = test.Substring(1); //"bcde"
```

Does this mean that `test` on the second line is not the same object as `test` on the first line? ie the compiler created a new instance of the string object and called it 'test' and the first 'test' gets sent to the garbage collector?

If so, is this anything I need to be concerned about?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is exactly what happens, except that string literals are interned and can never be GC'd.

Also, objects don't have names; instead, it creates a new `String` instance and makes your variable refer to it.

Comment: "Also, objects don't have names; instead, it creates a new String instance and makes your variable refer to it." Ah yes, very good. Didn't realise they can never be GC'd. Is that something I should concern myself with with regards to memory resources?

Comment: @rory: No; you probably don't have megabutes of string **literals**.

Answer (score 13):

Schabse's answer is of course correct; I however would go further in clarifying your thinking.

> Does this mean that test on the second line is not the same object as test on the first line?

Yes. `test` is the name of a *variable*. (Keep in mind that not all variables have names, but this one does.)  A *variable* stores a *value*.  A *reference* is a kind of *value*. You begin by assigning a *reference* to a particular string to `test`. You then assign a *different* reference on the next line.

> the compiler created a new instance of the string object and called it 'test' and the first 'test' gets sent to the garbage collector?

The compiler did no such thing. A *compiler* is a device which translates a program written in one language into a program written in another language. The C# compiler translates C# into a portable executable containing MSIL code and metadata.  That code instructs the CLR to create strings.

> the CLR, when running this program fragment, created a new instance of the string object and called it 'test'

No, the CLR created a new instance of `string` and assigned a reference to that instance to the variable named `test`. The *instance* is not the thing that has a name. The *variable which stores a reference to the instance* is the thing which has a name. Do not confuse the two!  If I have an address book called *My Address Book*, and the address book contains the address "Barry Obama, 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC", the name of the house at that address is still *The White House*, not *My Address Book*.

> The CLR created a new instance of the string object, assigns a reference to it to test, which already contains a reference. Since the previously-referred-to object is now no longer referred to by any root, the garbage collector immediately frees it.

No. First off, references to literal strings need not be freed. Second, supposing that the thrown-away reference was not to a literal, the garbage collector runs on its own schedule, when it runs at all. There is no requirement that the string *ever* be freed. Of course, when the process terminates -- if it does -- then all process memory will be freed.

So now we can address your original question:

> If strings are immutable, does that mean a value reassignment creates a new string object with the same name?

The question is incoherent because (1) reference semantics are completely independent of whether or not strings are immutable, (2) objects don't have names, *variables* have names.  Can you rephrase your question?

> Is this anything I need to be concerned about?

Gaining a correct understanding of the fundamentals of C# is absolutely something you should be concerned about if you want to be a C# programmer.